# DiscordiaJQUERY - Using DIVs after load(ing) an external page

Tags: jquery

Before openning this thread, I googled this query during this night without success. It seems that it's a basic and common use of JQuery:

- load an external page (a table with `#IMGs` content) inside a (`<DIV id="content"></DIV>`)
- To access a specific ID : no problem using .live function

The problem is I want the list (Or array) of the `IMGs#IDs` (newly) charged.
When I try:

```
 var imgIDs = $('#content').find('img').map(function(){
    return this.id;
 }).get();
 alert (imgIDs.length);
```

The alert always give me `0` ! It's empty.

How could I proceed ?

Comment: @Caspar: Thanks for reformating the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Your description makes it sound like you're using `.live` because you don't know when the content inside `#content` has loaded. This is also a problem for the code example you give. You should run it from the `success` (or maybe `complete`) handler of the load. Eg. if you're using something like the following to populate the `#content` div:

```
$('#content').load('/mydata');
```

Then try this to execute your function once it's been populated:

```
$('#content').load('/mydata', function() {
    var imgIDs = $('#content').find('img').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    alert(imgIDs.length);
});
```

See the [jQuery load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on how this example works.

If you give a js fiddle or link demonstrating the 'real' problem, that'd help me be more sure about what you're asking.

Comment: I already done this without success (Exactly the code you submited), but I didn't try with the 'success' or 'complete' attribute. Will do at once!

Comment: !! I'M SO CONFUSED !! Here is the code I used before sendind the post:$('#contents').load("prodView.html p#prodD", function()
                     {
                      var imgIDs = $('#contents').find('img').map(function(){
                return this.id;
             }).get();
       alert (imgIDs.length);
                     });

Comment: Can you provide a link to a test page? That'd most likely help with figuring out what the issue is...

Comment: your code works fine !! Thank you very much for your time and your help

Comment: As you see in my own code, I tried to reach a specific ID p#prodD and it seems that's wath make problem...